Chern class of $\mathcal O(d)$
I was reading Vincent Bouchard notes notes. On section $3.3.2$, I face some issue:

Let $X$ be a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{C P}^m$ defined as the zero-locus of a degree $d$ polynomial $p$. We can view $p$ as a section of the holomorphic line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(d)$. Consider $T^{(1,0)} X$, the holomorphic tangent bundle of $X$. We define the normal bundle $N_X$ on $X$ to be the quotient $N_X=\frac{T^{(1,0)} \mathbb{C P}^m \mid X}{T^{(1,0)} X}$. Consequently, we have the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow T^{(1,0)} X \rightarrow T^{(1,0)} \mathbb{C} \mathbb{P}^m\mid_X \rightarrow N_X \rightarrow 0$. Roughly speaking, on $X$, the section $p$ maps points of $X$ to 0 in the fibers of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(d)$ since $X$ is defined as the zero-locus of $p$. Thus, $p$ serves as a coordinate near $X$, and in fact, the normal bundle $N_X$ of $X$ is simply $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{CP} m}(d)\mid_X$.

Question 1: I didn't understand how the normal bundle $N_X$ of $X$ is simply $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{CP} m}(d)\mid_X$?

The above exact sequence then becomes
$$
0 \rightarrow T^{(1,0)} X \rightarrow T^{(1,0)} \mathbb{C P}^m\mid_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P} m}(d)\mid_X \rightarrow 0,
$$
which implies that $c(X)=c\left(\mathbb{C P}^m\right) / c\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(d)\right)$. $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(d)$ is a line bundle, so $c\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(d)\right)=1+c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(d)\right)$. We know from above that $c\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(1)\right)=1+x$. Therefore, its Chern character is $\operatorname{ch}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P} m}(1)\right)=e^x$. It follows that $\operatorname{ch}\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P} m}(d)\right)=e^{d x}=1+c_1\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(d)\right)+\ldots$, hence
$c\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(d)\right)=1+d x$.

Question 2: I didn't understand how $c\left(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C P}^m}(d)\right)=1+d x$?
It will be a great help if anyone could shed some light.

As is alluded to in the sentences which follow, the answer to question 1 is the adjunction formula. If $V$ is a smooth analytic hypersurface of a compact complex manifold $M$, then $V$ is a divisor and has an associated line bundle $\mathcal{O}(V)$ on $M$. The adjunction formula states that the normal bundle of $V$ in $M$ is $\mathcal{O}(V)|_V$; see the discussion on pages 145 and 146 of Principles of Algebraic Geometry by Griffiths and Harris for example. In this case, $X$ is the zero set of a section of $\mathcal{O}(d)$, so $\mathcal{O}(X) \cong \mathcal{O}(d)$ and hence $N_X \cong \mathcal{O}(X)|_X \cong \mathcal{O}(d)|_X$.
For question 2, note that for a complex line bundle $L$ we have
$$\operatorname{ch}(L) = e^{c_1(L)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{c_1(L)^n}{n!} = 1 + c_1(L) + \frac{1}{2}c_1(L)^2 + \dots$$
so $\operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(d)) = 1 + c_1(\mathcal{O}(d)) + \frac{1}{2}c_1(\mathcal{O}(d))^2 + \dots$ On the other hand, we know $\operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(d)) = e^{dx}$, so
$$\operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(d)) = e^{dx} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(dx)^n}{n!} = 1 + dx + \frac{1}{2}d^2x^2 + \dots$$
Comparing the degree 2 components of both expressions for $\operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(d))$, we see that $c_1(\mathcal{O}(d)) = dx$, and hence $c(\mathcal{O}(d)) = 1 + c_1(\mathcal{O}(d)) = 1 + dx$.

Thanks for your answer @MichaelAlbanese . I want to know more about, "On the other hand, we know $\operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(d)) = e^{dx}$". Is there any reference where I can have the proof? And thanks again.

Note that $\mathcal{O}(d) = \mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes d}$ and $\operatorname{ch}(E\otimes F) = \operatorname{ch}(E)\operatorname{ch}(F)$, so $\operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(d)) = \operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(1)^{\otimes d}) = \operatorname{ch}(\mathcal{O}(1))^d = (e^x)^d = e^{dx}$.
